# Dropping marker on event, in google maps

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to make so the marker i hidden until the map is clicked.

If i remove the listener the marker is where it should be, and everything works, when i add it the marker is permanently gone.

I've looked through both the google api and several websites(including this one), my roomate even had a look at it, i just can't seem to get it working.

My understanding is that 'click' in this case is a google specific thing, since browsers handle events like that slightly differently, so maybe the listener is the problem.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(55.680313, 12.548468);

function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {

     center:myCenter,
     zoom:15,
     mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     };

var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'rightclick', function(event) {

     var marker=new google.maps.Marker({

          position:myCenter,
          animation:google.maps.Animation.DROP

          });
});

marker.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not bind event to map container?

```
document.getElementById("googleMap").onmousedown = function(e) {
    if ((e.which && e.which == 3) || (e.button && e.button == 2)) {
        var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
            position:myCenter,
            animation:google.maps.Animation.DROP
        });
        document.getElementById("googleMap").onmousedown = undefined;
    }
}
```

We set `onclick` as `undefined` to disable creating marker after first click.

UPD: Sorry. Noticed, that you want bind right-click. Updated code.

Comment: i ended up using geocodezips solution because it only required to me change a single line, but i tried this just because, and it worked nicely too. thank you

Answer (score 1):

I get a javascript error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: marker is not defined
```

on this line:

```
marker.setMap(map);
```

Change:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'rightclick', function(event) {
     var marker=new google.maps.Marker({

          position:myCenter,
          animation:google.maps.Animation.DROP

          });
});

marker.setMap(map);
```

To:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'rightclick', function(event) {
     var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
          position:myCenter,
          animation:google.maps.Animation.DROP
          });
     marker.setMap(map);
});
```

Or:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'rightclick', function(event) {
     var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,  
          position:myCenter,
          animation:google.maps.Animation.DROP
          });
});
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_markerOnClick.html)

Comment: I can't believe i missed that for so long! working perfectly now! tyvm

Comment: upvoted since it uses map eventListener, not DOM eventListener. We should not mix map api and dom api.